# No of pairs of elements whose XOR satisfies a condition

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

We are given a set of $n$ non-negative integers. We need to find the number of pairs of integers from this set whose $XOR$ is $ = K$.

My approach is to sort the integers which takes $O(NlogN)$. Then for each element $a_i$ find $a_i\oplus K$. Make a binary search for the result. If it exists increment the counter. This can be done in a total of $O(NlogN)$.

Now, I want to extend the question to find number of such pairs whose $XOR$ is $\le K$. Obviously, an algorithm better than $O(N^2)$ is needed.

Comment: You can do better in your first algorithm by hashing the integers and storing.  Then hash $a_i\oplus K$ and check for collision.  This will improve $Nlog N$ to just $N$.

Comment: @vadim123 I always wonder how do one hash integers. How many bits are there to account for?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: @vadim123 I suppose you miss the point. An only perfect hash for unrestricted integers is the value of the integer itself. That is, constant time access is only possible for bounded integers.

Comment: The integers aren't unrestricted, you're given them in some format so they are bounded.  My approach is to trade speed for storage; in any case it's not answering the 2nd question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's make the problem a little more general and have *two* sets of input numbers $A$ and $B$, and ask for the number of pairs $(a,b)\in A\times B$ such that $a \oplus b \le K$.

If $K=0$ then the answer is just $|A\cap B|$. Otherwise let $K=2^p+Q$ with $Q<2^p$. (This is just finding the most significant set bit in $K$).

Then partition both $A$ and $B$ into subsets according to the quotient $\lfloor a/2^p \rfloor$ for each number $a$. Whenever there's both a subset $A_i$ and a subset $B_i$ with the *same* quotient, that gives us $|A_i|\times|B_i|$ pairs that xor to something less than $K$ -- indeed, less than $2^p$.

On the other hand, we can also pair up the partitions such that the subset of $A$ corresponding to the quotient $x$ is matched up to the subset of $B$ corresponding to the quotient $x\oplus 1$. When we xor numbers from two such subsets together we get something between $2^p$ and $2^{p+1}$, which will be $\le K$ if the xor of the *remainders* is $\le Q$. Count the numbers of relevant pairs between the two partitions recursively.

If we start by setting $A=B=$ the input set, this algorithm gives the number of *ordered* pairs that xor to something $\le K$. We can get the number of *unordered* pairs instead by noting $(a,a)$ is a qualifying pair for every input number $a$ -- and these $n$ pairs are counted exactly once, whereas everything *else* was counted exactly twice. So to get the number of unordered pairs, add $n$ and divide by two at the very end. (Or subtract $n$ if you don't want to count $a\oplus a$ as "pairs" at all).

---

**Time complexity.** If we sort the set of input numbers once and for all at the beginning, the order will be preserved each time we take remainders for a recursive invocation of the algorithm, so the partitioning in each step takes linear time. Each of the $n$ input numbers ends up in at most one recursive call for each $p$, and there are at most $\log K$ levels in the recursion, so the total time complexity in $O(n\log n + n\log K)$.

It feels like it should be possible to prove that this running time is actually linear in the size of the the input in bits (rather than the number of input numbers), but the details of how to dispose of the $\log K$ factor are a bit murky if $K$ is larger than most but not all of the input numbers. Perhaps it isn't true.

Comment: what is 2^p????

Comment: @RamapriyaSridharan: The highest nonzero bit in $K$.

Comment: Is it possible to provide an example to show how this would work?

Comment: @RamapriyaSridharan: Example: If $256\le K < 512$, then $p=8$.